# WPF: How to shift Unicode character into a shared resource?

Tags: c#, wpf

I have this XAML:

```
<TextBlock Text="Message with unicode char: &#x24D8;"/>
```

Is there some way to shift that unicode character `&#x24D8;` into a shared resource (like a constant or a `StaticResource`)?

### What I have tried

#### Method 1

This works fine, but it requires a valid binding to work:

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.Resources>
        <system:String x:Key="ToolTipChar">{0} &#x24D8;</system:String>
    </Grid.Resources>
    <TextBlock Text="{Binding MyText, StringFormat={StaticResource ToolTipChar}}"/>
</Grid>
```

And in code behind:

```
public string MyText { get; set; } = "Message with unicode char: ";
```

#### Method 2

This method seems like it might work, but no luck:

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.Resources>
        <system:String x:Key="ToolTipChar">{0} &#x24D8;</system:String>
    </Grid.Resources>
    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Nothing, FallbackValue='Message with unicode char: ', StringFormat={StaticResource ToolTipChar}}"/>
</Grid>
```

Comment: What's keeping you from doing it? Do you get any errors?

Comment: @nvoigt If the text has a `{Binding}`, I can use `StringFormat={StaticResource ToolTipChar}`, but if the text is not bound, nothing I've tried seems to work.

Comment: That's true I don't think there is a (simple, official, non-hacky) way to do that without a binding.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, this should work:

```
<Window.Resources>
    <s:String x:Key="ToolTipChar">{0}&#x24D8;</s:String>
</Window.Resources>
...
<TextBlock Text="{Binding Source='Message with unicode char:', StringFormat={StaticResource ToolTipChar}}" />
```

Answer (score 2):

This will also work:

```
<Window.Resources>
    <system:String x:Key="ToolTipChar">&#x24D8;</system:String>
</Window.Resources>
...
<TextBlock Text="{Binding StringFormat='Message with unicode char: {0}', 
                          Source={StaticResource ToolTipChar}}" />
```

I find it slightly more readable, and easier to understand, than putting the replacement token directly in the `string` resource.

Answer (score 2):

Another alternative which doesn't involve binding is to use `TextBlock.Inlines`

```
<my:String x:Key="TooltipSign">&#x24D8;</my:String>
```

```
<TextBlock HorizontalAlignment="Right" Margin="10">
    <Run Text="Message with unicode char:"/>
    <Run Text="{StaticResource TooltipSign}" 
         FontWeight="Bold" Foreground="Orange" Background="Black"/>
</TextBlock>
```

`TextBlock.Inlines` is a content property of TextBlock, so `<TextBlock.Inlines>` tag can be omitted. Inlines provide additional decorating possibilities, like coloring part of the text:

[image: screenshot]